# Display Distinct records with random generate and limit

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on below query and its working fine. But now I want to fetch records from database with random data so every time differnt records comes as return.

**Working Query**

```
$limit = " LIMIT 0," . ($pageNumber * intval($page_record));
$query = "SELECT * FROM logos L WHERE L.status=1 ".$limit;
```

I have tried `ORDER BY RAND()`.

```
$limit = " LIMIT 0," . ($pageNumber * intval($page_record));
$query = "SELECT * FROM logos L WHERE L.status=1 ORDER BY  RAND() ".$limit;
```

**Problem :** Above query give me same data more than once.

**1) Should I able to achieve distinct records with random records and limit?**

**2) If not possible above then should I achieve it by PHP code?**

I am little bit confuse. Please help if any good solution or idea.

If anything wrong then paste it in comment rather then minus vote.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *random* not equal to *different + unique* so if random(1,5) returns' 1,2,3,4,5 or 5,4,3,2,1 or 4,3,2,1,5 they all are random. but for sure not unique against each other if those numbers are id in database table

Comment: so i can not achieve it?

Comment: **ORDER BY  RAND()** is exactly what you need. you should just accept that sometimes it returns some id that you already have seen. but that behavior is correct

Comment: Yes problem is sometimes I am getting same id which i already got before.

Comment: that is how random works. and in most cases that is acceptable and good behavior. if you want to avoid that - you should keep all used id somewhere and add `AND id NOT IN ( id1, id2, id3 ...)` where id1, id2, id3 are ids that you saved somewhere before... but this has very small sense to me

Comment: Should i achieve it by php like already got data store in array and compare it with new. Something like that ?

Comment: my opinion you should accept repetition when random. there is nothing wrong with that. the bigger table you have the less repetition you'll get for order by random.

Comment: How much rows do you have in your table ? One solution in pure SQL would be to `INSERT INTO temptable SELECT ID FROM logos L WHERE L.status=1 ORDER BY RAND()`  (so with no `LIMIT` to insert full results) and then make your pagination with an `INNER JOIN` on the temptable. But that approach is not good if you have a lot of rows.

Comment: @Thomus I will try your solution.